# how to count total replies and show them in descending order in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i have two table questions and replies. inside replies i am storing all the replies of the question so in my replies table i have field question id.
i want to count number of replies against the question and want to show them in a descending order.
such as the the question who has the most replies should come first.
how i can count them and show them in descending order?

```
$data=DB::table('questions')
            ->join('replies', 'questions.id','=','replies.q_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data=DB::table('questions')
        ->join('replies', 'questions.id','=','replies.q_id')
        ->groupBy('questions.id')
        ->select('questions.id' , DB::raw('COUNT(1) as total_replies'))
        ->orderByDesc('total_replies')
        ->get();
```

Comment: it is only showing id and total replies count i want to show all the values in the database tables as well.

Comment: @Zaeem so add them into select

Comment: thank u with little alteration it worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: @Zaeem good luck